# Databricks: SQL Pivot does not work - but Python does

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to pivot a SQL table in Databricks on the `FeatureName` column using the `FeatureDescription` column as the value.

But somehow the SQL query that I have resolves to null values being populated across the table.

Here is the original table:

| AddressKey | FeatureName | FeatureDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11101 | Groups | AG WAREHOUSE |
| 11101 | National Groups | AG WAREHOUSE |
| 5528 | National Groups | AIRR |
| 5528 | Groups | AUSTRALIAN INDEPENDENT RURAL RESELLERS |

Here is the SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT AddressKey, FeatureName, FeatureDescription
   FROM radp_dev_cat.rdp_svr_sales.vw_customerfeatures) src
PIVOT (
  max(FeatureDescription)
  FOR FeatureName IN (
    'Carcasspricecategory' AS Carcasspricecategory,
    'Channel' AS Channel,
    'Class' AS Class,
    'Contractor' AS Contractor,
    'DebtorCategory' AS DebtorCategory,
    'DomesticCustTradingasExport' AS DomesticCustTradingasExport,
    'FarmingOperations' AS FarmingOperations,
    'FarmingProductionType' AS FarmingProductionType,
    'FeatureName' AS FeatureName,
    'FMInternalRegions' AS FMInternalRegions,
    'Groups' AS Groups,
    'MillITSupplierType' AS MillITSupplierType,
    'NationalGroups' AS NationalGroups,
    'PaymentMethod' AS PaymentMethod,
    'PurchaseGroup' AS PurchaseGroup,
    'RegisteredforGST' AS RegisteredforGST,
    'SalesGroup' AS SalesGroup,
    'SiteBaxters' AS SiteBaxters,
    'SiteCorowaMeats' AS SiteCorowaMeats,
    'SiteDVP' AS SiteDVP,
    'SiteFeedmill' AS SiteFeedmill,
    'SiteNSWWholesale' AS SiteNSWWholesale,
    'Type' AS Type
  )
);
```

The result:

| AddressKey | Carcass price category | Channel | Class | Contractor | Debtor Category | Domestic Cust Trading as Export | FM Internal Regions | Farming Operations | Farming Production Type | Payment Method | Purchase Group | Registered for GST | Sales Group | Site Baxters | Site Corowa Meats | Site DVP | Site Feedmill | Site NSW Wholesale | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 24 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 1000 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |

All null values for all columns across the table.

I tried using `any`, `first`, `max`, etc. for the aggregate function. Same result.

But it works why I do the same thing using Python:

```
%python
import pandas as pd

df = spark.sql('SELECT * FROM  radp_dev_cat.rdp_svr_sales.vw_customerfeatures')

df_pivot = df.groupBy('AddressKey').pivot('FeatureName').agg({"FeatureDescription": "first"}).toPandas()

df_pivot
```

| AddressKey | Carcass price category | Channel | Class | Contractor | Debtor Category | Domestic Cust Trading as Export | FM Internal Regions | Farming Operations | Farming Production Type | Payment Method | Purchase Group | Registered for GST | Sales Group | Site Baxters | Site Corowa Meats | Site DVP | Site Feedmill | Site NSW Wholesale | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | None | MEAT WHOLESALE | MEAT | None | None | None | None | None | None | EFT | GRAIN GROWERS | No | None | No | No | No | Yes | No | BUTCHER |
| 24 | None | RETAIL | MEAT | None | None | None | None | None | None | EFT | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | None | BUTCHER |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Why does this happen? Is something wrong with my SQL query?

Thanks.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question  and edit your question

Comment: have you checked for spaces in the Text or add a TRIM to FeatureName ?

Comment: The images are unreadable, and data must be also in text form

Comment: Ich no the problem is that you don't need a trim but an upper, the text in the first image is all upper character but the text you compare is only the first character big so none is ever going to be equal the the pivot will find a match

Comment: @nbk - I have edited the question to include markdown tables instead of images. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: All the table and names are not equal for example you have groups in the first table and in the query but not in the result. Also try to find with a simple select of the texted in the IN of the pivot and see if there is a match because the database thinks that you have none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the underlying view that had the FeatureName, FeatureDescription data. The columns had trailing whitespace in the records so none of the PIVOT columns matched.

| FeatureName | len(FeatureName) | FeatureDescription | len(FeatureDescription) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Debtor Category | 50 | TRADE | 70 |
| Type | 50 | DISTRIBUTOR | 70 |
| Class | 50 | LOCAL | 70 |

I trimmed the underlying view and it worked.

Thanks for the insight @nbk.